# How to write highlight_file to textarea?

Tags: php, html

I want to write text from highlight_file to the html textarea... but not sure how?
Note:  I am able to write the screen the colored text, but I want it loaded into a box where I can modify the text.  thx

```
<?php
...
$code =  highlight_file($_POST[filename]);//not sure if this works to write to $code
...
?>
<html>
<textarea type="text" name="code" rows="40" cols="120">
<?php echo $code; ?>
</textarea> <!this does not work>
</html>
```

Comment: highlight_file is not good way for showing in text area becuase it return with html it will be good use file_get_contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP docs:

> ```
> mixed highlight_file ( string $filename [, bool $return = false ] )
> ```

So, use `$code = highlight_file($_POST['filename'], true);`

As a side-note: You do realize that this allows anyone with access to that script to read the code of **all** your files (PHP and other)? This includes any config files etc. which might contain database passwords.

Comment: this loads the file but not in the colored text format that shows when just executing this from PHP.  Is there anyway to have that done?  Also this displayed more text that what showed up when doing highlight_file from PHP.  Not sure there either.  thx

Comment: If you do not get syntax highlighting it sounds like the php code in the file does not contain `<?php` tags and thus is not PHP code for the PHP parser (which is used by `highlight_file`)

Comment: running     highlight_file     from PHP highlights the text.  But the text in the html textarea is not highlighted.   But all the color codes and much more are displayed in the textarea.

Comment: textarea is meant for text, not html. You should try some WYSIWYG editor, like TinyMCE or CKeditor.